# Python optimizing reshape operations in nested for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization, reshape

I am looking for help in finding a more pythonic/broadcasting way to optimize the two following array reshaping functions:

```
import numpy

def A_reshape(k,m,A):
    """
    Reshaping input float ndarray A of shape (x,y) 
    to output array A_r of shape (k,y,m)
    where k,m are user known dimensions
    """
    if A.ndim == 1: # in case A is flat make it (len(A),1)
        A = A.reshape((len(A),1))
    y = A.shape[1]
    A_r = np.zeros((k,y,m))
    for i in range(0,y,1):
        u = A[:,i].reshape((k,m))
        for j in range(0,m,1):
            A_r[:,i,j] = u[:,j]
    return A_r

def B_reshape(n,m,B):
    """
    Reshaping input float ndarray B of shape (z,y) 
    to output array B_r of shape (n,y,m)
    where n,m are user known dimensions
    """
    if B.ndim == 1: # in case B is flat make it (len(A),1)
        B = B.reshape((len(B),1))
    y = B.shape[1]
    B_r = np.zeros((n,y,m))
    for i in range(0,y,1):
        v = B[:,i]
        for j in range(0,m,1):
            B_r[:,i,j] = v[j*n:(j+1)*n]
    return B_r
```

A may be of shape (33,10), B of shape (192,10) given k=11, n=64 and  m=3 for example.

Any suggestions to improve my understanding of numpy reshaping techniques and avoid the use of `for` loops would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So `k*m ==  x`?  You want reshape to (k,m,y) followed by an axis swap?

Comment: Please provide some simple example of proposed transformation. Just to be sure that people understand it correctly. Your task can be achieved with np.transpose  or np.moveaxis, next reshape and apply reversed np.transpose/np.move axis

Comment: I just added some typical shapes. I am currently looking at np.swapaxis doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
def A_reshape(k,m,A):
    A2 = A.reshape(k,m,-1)
    A2 = np.moveaxis(A2, 2, 1)
    return A2
```

Assume that A's shape is (x,y). Initially, the first dimension is expanded:

`(x,y) -> (k,m,y)`

Next, the axis of size y is moved from position 2 to position 1.

`(k,m,y) -> (k,y,m)`

The case of B_reshape is more complicated because the dimension transformation is:

`(x,y) -> (m,n,y) # not (n,m,y)`

`(m,n,y) -> (n,y,m) # m is moved to the end`

The code is:

```
def B_reshape(n,m,B):
    B2 = B.reshape(m,n,-1)
    B2 = np.moveaxis(B2, 0, 2)
    return B2
```

Comment: Value -1 tells numpy to compute the dimension automatically. Very useful feature

Comment: @Yacola Thank you, but B reshaping is slightly different. My answer is not full yet. I'll try to work it out asap